# django+nginx deployment not loading static files correctly

Tags: python, django, reactjs, nginx, wsgi

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 13.xx.xx.xxx;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/studykarma/django-react-redux-base/src/;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/studykarma/django-react-redux-base/src/djangoreactredux.sock;
    }
}
```

my nginx config file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_dist'),
)
```

my settings.py

I have my static files in static_dist folder and my reactjs code in static
folder.

My static files are not loading and giving me 404,
If i change path to /static_dist/ then also i am getting empty content.

I am using this template: https://github.com/Seedstars/django-react-redux-base

Comment: I would expect `location /static/` to be the same as `STATIC_ROOT` from your settings. Have you run `collectstatic` to copy your files to the static root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this,

```
location /static_root/ { root /home/ubuntu/studykarma/django-react-redux-base/src/static_r‌​oot/; }
```

it will work

Answer (score 2):

**About Nginx configuration**

```
location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/studykarma/django-react-redux-base/src/;
 }
```

This configuration tells Nginx that on accessing via say example.com/static/app.js, look app.js file inside `src` folder `root`, if you want `static_dist`, then the configuration change will be

```
location /static/{
   root /home/ubuntu/studykarma/django-react-redux-base/src/path/to/static_dist/;
}
```

**About Django configuration**

Your Django settings is logically wrong,

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
```

Above settings tells django that you expect all your static files from `STATICFILES_DIRS` to `STATIC_ROOT`, the configuration is effective/used by django when you use `collectstatic` django manage command, which ineffect copies all your files from `STATICFILES_DIRS` to `STATIC_ROOT`( but this also means that, you have to point `/static/` location nginx config to `static_root` instead of `static_dist`.

Comment: I ran `collectstatic` and `static_root` folder got created and i modified `location` block to `location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/studykarma/django-react-redux-base/src/static_root/;
    }` but still getting 404

Comment: `location /static_root/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/studykarma/django-react-redux-base/src/static_root/;
    }`  this one worked for me